# Uniqueness of the integrand of a stochastic integral

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Given a progressively measurable processes $\Delta_s(\omega),\Delta'_s(\omega)$ and real numbers $z',z$, there was a claim that if $$\int_0^T(\Delta_s-\Delta's)\mathrm{d}X_t=z-z'$$ for a non-trivial local martingale $X$, then $\Delta_s=\Delta'_s$. (All equal is meant to be in almost surely sense). I don't see why it is follows. Any hint are appreciated.

Comment: Do you assume that the equation holds for all $T>0$ or just for some fixed $T>0$...?The counterexamples [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/193735) seem to suggest that assertion is, in general, wrong for fixed $T$ (... but perhaps I'm missing something).

Comment: @saz Would it work for all t? Or with some more additional assumptions?

Comment: Well, under some additional assumptions it holds true, yes... but it would be good to know which statement exactly you are after. It seems that you read this claim somewhere, so perhaps you can look up the precise statement?